# Why [NSBundle localizedStringForKey] does not return the iPhone language localised string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Why `localizedStringForKey` returns the localization of the development language first instead of the language of the iPhone? The "Bundle Search Pattern" in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html) says:

> If a .lproj folder exists for the preferred language, that localization is used. Otherwise, the bundle searches for a .lproj folder matching the next preferred language, and so on, until one is found. If there is no localization for a preferred language, the bundle chooses the development language localization.
>
> Then the bundle searches for the resource in the following order [...]

But it does not make sense to me.

The test iPhone is in Chinese, french keyboard, the bundle contains 32 languages and the development language localization in English. I don't understand why it makes sense to return the English localization first. Why not is the Chinese one as this the iPhone language?

```
NSArray* arr = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
// ( zh-Hant-FR, en-FR, fr-FR )

NSArray* localizations = [bundle localizations];
// ar,bg,ca,cs,da,de,el,en,es,fr,he,hu,id,it,ja,ko,ms,nb,nl,nn,pl,pt,pt_BR,ro,ru,sv,th,tr,uk,vi,zh-Hans,zh-Hant

NSArray* preferredLocalizations = [bundle localizations];
// same output

<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string>

NSString* str = [bundle localizedStringForKey:@"hello" value:@"" table:@"mytable"];
// hello
```

How should I fix this? I would like `localizedStringForKey`to always return the iPhone language localization whatever the development language.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

`NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue("requiredTranslationKey", @"StringFileName", [NSBundle mainBundle], @"", @"");`

Comment: I am not convinced. ```NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue``` is a macro for ```localizedStringForKey:value:table:```, the exact function I use.